# Asp.net Re-enable disabled button on Response

Tags: javascript, asp.net, response

After some extensive searching, I can't seem to find a solution to this particular problem.

I have a button which calls a server-side method which uses response to send a Zip file to the browser, and uses Javascript to disable the button to prevent multiple clicks.

This is all well and good. The problem I cannot find an answer to is how to re-enable the button once the Response.Write() is fired and sends the file.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the page is refreshing, could you re-enable the button with a quick:

```
    if (postback)
        Button.enable
    end if
```

Comment: I tried. It never hits that state. I must admit I don't fully understand the page states that are involved in using the "Response.Write" to download a file. Thank you for the input though!